# Why is the BEL character mapped to Critical Stop?

Tags: powershell

I am on Windows 10 build 10074.

Why is the BEL character mapped to the `Critical Stop` program event sound?

```
write-host $([system.char]7)
```

Is it possible to change it to `Default Beep`?

Answer (score 1):

The sound made when outputting ASCII `0x7` (`BEL`), is controlled by [a dedicated System Driver, `beep.sys`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2010/01/04/what-s-up-with-the-beep-driver-in-windows-7.aspx) (I doubt this has changed in Windows 10).

AFAIK, you'll either have to stop it completely (`net stop beep`) or reverse engineer it and write your own